# Tcl error wrong # args: should be "set varName ?newValue?"

Tags: unix, tcl, vmd

I tried to run the following Tcl script and got the error:

```
wrong # args: should be "set varName ?newValue?"
```

What does this mean?

Note: The script includes terms specific to VMD progra

```
set dir plugins/noarch/tcl/vmdICE1.0 source $dir pkgIndex.tcl vmd_install_extension vmdICE xrmsdgui_tk_cb "Analysis/vmdICE"
```

Comment: pls provide the entire error trace, not just the error message. also, the script fragment posted does not seem the one you are actually trying to run: `pkgIndex.tcl` as a command?

Answer (score 0):

Tcl really cares about newlines. It treats them like many other languages treat semicolons, as a command terminator. (You can use semicolons in Tcl too if you want, but that's uncommon.)

Because of that, your script:

```
set dir plugins/noarch/tcl/vmdICE1.0 source $dir pkgIndex.tcl vmd_install_extension vmdICE xrmsdgui_tk_cb "Analysis/vmdICE"
```

is hopelessly wrong. It's *one* call of a command, `set`, with *far too many arguments*. If we add in the newlines in the most likely places, we get:

```
set dir plugins/noarch/tcl/vmdICE1.0
source $dir pkgIndex.tcl
vmd_install_extension vmdICE
xrmsdgui_tk_cb "Analysis/vmdICE"
```

Now that's still wrong, but it's much closer to right. The last key bit of fixing is to make the filename to `source` correct:

```
set dir plugins/noarch/tcl/vmdICE1.0
source $dir/pkgIndex.tcl
vmd_install_extension vmdICE
xrmsdgui_tk_cb "Analysis/vmdICE"
```

I don't know whether that will work for you, but it at least looks sane to me.